# app.config file is not readed between referenced projects on VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have 2 projects on visual studio 2008 , lets call them A and B. Project A is a windows service with its own config file. Project A is running itself as a windows service on a production environment. Project B is calling some functions of Project A. Project A is referenced on project B and everything is working on development environment. The problem is that when building project A and B, on production environment Project A is not reading its own config file! I mean, Project A (windows service) only reads its own config file when it is running as a service. But when it is called from another project B...config file seems to be embedded on "B.exe" file.

Any help? Thank you

Comment: I think it's better to use/create another library that write into specific file and share the settings there. So everytime you need to configuration you just need to add the lib and enter the configuration path constant.

Comment: You seem confused about how assemblies interact.  For each application, there is only one config file.  If A is running as a service then it is an application and it has its own config file.  If B is running as an application and referencing A as a library then A is NOT an application in this context.  B is the application so B's config file is the only one that matters.  If you want B to use A as a library then you need to copy A's config data into B's config file.

Comment: To be frank, it seems completely wacky to be using the same assembly as both a service and a library. You should at a redesign. Move the common functionality into a third project that both applications can reference and then copy the config from the libraries config file into the other two.